# why does memory_order_seq_cst didn't protect my atomic-operation running sequence?

Tags: c++, memory

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
std::atomic_bool b(false);
std::atomic_bool lock{false};

void producer() {
  b.store(true, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
  lock.store(true, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
}

void consume() {
  while (!lock.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst))
    ;
  assert(b.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst));

  b.store(false, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
  lock.store(false, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
}

int main() {
  std::thread t1([&]() {
    while (true)
      consume();
  });
  std::thread t2([&]() {
    while (true)
      producer();
  });

  t1.join();
  t2.join();
}
```

Assert in consume should never fail, memory_order_seq_cst guarentee that atmoic operation run in the order that they are wrote;

But assert fail happened :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void producer() {
  b.store(true, std::memory_order_seq_cst);      // 1
  lock.store(true, std::memory_order_seq_cst);   // 2
}

void consume() {
  while (!lock.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst))
    ;                                            // 3
  assert(b.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst));     // 4

  b.store(false, std::memory_order_seq_cst);      // 5
  lock.store(false, std::memory_order_seq_cst);   // 6
}
```

The following steps will make the assert fail: 1 -> 5 -> 6 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4

Comment: wow ,that's clear ,thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis would be correct for a single pair of `produce()` and `consume()` but not for an endless loop of them.

| Thread 1 | Thread 2 |
| --- | --- |
| `b.store(true, std::memory_order_seq_cst);` |  |
| `lock.store(true, std::memory_order_seq_cst);` |  |
|  | `while (!lock.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst));` |
|  | `assert(b.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst));` |
| `b.store(true, std::memory_order_seq_cst);` |  |
|  | `b.store(false, std::memory_order_seq_cst);` |
|  | `lock.store(false, std::memory_order_seq_cst);` |
| `lock.store(true, std::memory_order_seq_cst);` |  |
|  | `while (!lock.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst));` |
|  | `assert(b.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst));` **Assert fires!** |

The table shows an ordering where `b` is false and `lock` is true.

If you want that guarantee, you need to have `produce` wait for `lock` to be false.

```
void producer() {
  while (lock.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst))
    ;
  b.store(true, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
  lock.store(true, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the guaranteen suggestion!